# Lync SDK get sent or received text

Tags: sdk, lync, instant-messaging

Before anything I already saw this post:
[Lync ConversationRemoved get current conversation text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10536331/lync-conversationremoved-get-current-conversation-text)

I implemented that solution, but I really need to get the already sent or received text. The thing is, although I have my application registered as automatically open, if I get messaged with my window closed, I loose the first text (that's just an example). Anybody know how can I get the text?

I can't find it anywhere. Not in `Conversation` class or `ConversationManager`.

English is not my native language, hope you can understand me anyways.

Comment: I might add that the application is a CWE (Conversation windows extention). Not a console application or similar

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the first text, I'm assuming you mean that the first line is missing? The text that starts the IM conversation can be found in the so-called "Toast".

The toast is the popup you get on your Lync client when a new conversation is started. In case of IM conversations, the first message is part of the toast and shown to the user in this popup. It is not send over the instant messaging flow.

MSDN documentation: [ToastMessage class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lync/microsoft.rtc.collaboration.toastmessage_di_3_uc_ocs14mreflyncuc3cr.aspx)

The `ToastMessage` is a property of `InviteReceivedEventArgs` [[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.rtc.collaboration.componentmodel.invitereceivedeventargs_di_3_uc_ocs14mreflyncuc3cr_members.aspx)]. Your incoming call handler will probably handle `CallReceivedEventArgs`, which inherits `InviteReceivedEventArgs`.

```
private void OnIncomingInstantMessagingCallReceived(
    object sender,
    CallReceivedEventArgs<InstantMessagingCall> e)
{
    var toast = e.ToastMessage; // There she is. Mind you it can be null too.
}
```

Comment: I find a workaround, using an exe application, to add a popup when someone is talking, and passing all the conversation. I'd tried that approach, but it only have the very first message, if before you open the conversation the other person spams text, you lose all of them

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you want to get the conversation that happened *before* your application connected? Like, getting a history? I don't think this is possible in the API - you can't use the API to look at historical data, only what is happening "now". You might have some success looking in the Lync database (though I don't know where!)

Comment: Not the history per se, I just need the text which is in the current conversation window. Not even with javascript??